# Where can I download older SQLite binaries?

Tags: sqlite, download

I've got a problem with my web application. A query that completes in a few seconds in SQLite 3.7.4 on Windows takes a whole 6 minutes in SQLite 3.6.22 on Linux. On the very same database file. It contains a few WHERE NOT EXISTS parts so I can imagine something has been optimised there.

But the SQLite version is fixed on the Linux side, it's bound to the distribution so I cannot update it. When I tried a current Linux binary and uploaded it to the server, the shell just said the file would not exist. It was there, ls found it and it was mode 755 by my own user...

And I can't find that specific version for Windows as well to try it in the other direction. The SQLite download site only contains the very current version and nothing else. There's not even an archive of older releases...

Does anybody know where I can find older versions? Preferably as binary as I don't want to spent hours to get it compiled.

Comment: What platform does your web application use? What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) in both cases?

Comment: It's a PHP application. The EXPLAIN command shows different output. The slow environment only lists table names, the quick environment (newer SQLite version) also lists indices. That may be the difference.

Comment: There are ways of suggesting or forcing SQLite to use an index, but his is not what you asked for in this question ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check out and compile older releases from the [Fossil repository](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html#fossil).